# How to eliminate the VFD noise affecting digital sensor reading?

Tags: arduino, filter, noise, isolation, interference

I have a problem getting correct readings from a 5v digital sensor connected to an Arduino Uno board. I get correct reading until I start the VFD that drives a 3-phase motor.
The sensor reading then becomes illogically wrong! until I stop the VFD again. I tried using a 100nf decoupling capacitor just before the Arduino input pin but it didn't help. I can't change or

The Arduino is powered by a buck converter, which is powered by a power supply that shares the same main with the VFD and I can't change that. The system is grounded, and I can't change any wires unfortunately.

How can I get rid of this interference?

[image]

Comment: There's little hope of being able to help you without a schematic and a picture of your setup and wiring.  Even then, if the system wasn't designed from the beginning for EMC then it may be really difficult solve the problem without major rework.

Comment: I added a schematic, please keep in mind that it's working properly until I start the VFD.. thank you

Comment: Why the two converters? It looks like you've got lots of ground / supply loops, that might be causing pickup problems. Can you add photo of the actual setup? Also worth trying ferrites on the supply lines.

Comment: Do you have the proper shielded VFD cable between the VFD and the motor? If not, you’d want to get some as this will go a long way to solving your problem.